# Accuracy decreases during fir neural network with Keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, autoencoder

I have this function that implements a neural network:

```
    def create(self, size_1l, size_2l, size_3l=0, size_4l=0):
    """
    This function build the denoising autoencoder
    using the parameters as size, the first is the input layer,
    the third and the fourth if equal to 0 are omitted.
    """
    input_layer = Input(shape=(size_1l, size_1l, 1))
    # encoder
    x = Conv2D(size_2l, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', use_bias=True)(input_layer)
    if size_3l > 0:
        x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
        x = Conv2D(size_3l, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', use_bias=True)(x)
    if size_4l > 0:
        x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
        x = Conv2D(size_4l, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', use_bias=True)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)  # encoded layer
    # decoder
    if size_4l > 0:
        x = Conv2D(size_4l, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', use_bias=True)(x)
        x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    if size_3l > 0:
        x = Conv2D(size_3l, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', use_bias=True)(x)
        x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = Conv2D(size_2l, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', use_bias=True)(x)
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    output_layer = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='tanh', padding='same', use_bias=True)(x)
    # building
    self.autoencoder = Model(input_layer, output_layer)
    self.autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And this code for the training:

```
    def train(self, training_data, target_data, training_test_data, target_test_data, epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=0):
    history = self.autoencoder.fit(training_data, target_data,
                                   epochs=epochs,
                                   batch_size=batch_size,
                                   shuffle=True,
                                   verbose=1,
                                   validation_data=(training_test_data, target_test_data))
```

The problem is that the accuracy value decreases constantly during the training, as you can see below:

[image: Output training]

Have some suggestions? What happens? Why the value of accuracy not increase during the learning?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't your loss be mse? Binar_crossentroy is a single dense output loss function

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you say! @djk47463

Comment: I'm saying that binary_crossentropy is for 2 class classification problems. I think you would be better off with mean squared error as you loss function